# Python: number of words in line

Tags: python

I have a file with a lot of lines. I need to count the number of words only in line 35. Is there an easy way to do so?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes, it is. Also, you may want to check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looping:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    print(len(f.split('\n')[34].split()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
num_words = None
num_lines = 0
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        num_lines += 1
        if num_lines == 35:
            num_words = len(line.split())
            break

print('The number of words on line 35 is ' + str(num_words))
```